# Удаленный компьютер не видет сервер TFTP

Tags: ubuntu, администрирование, tftp

настроил на ubuntu tftp, на сервере на котором установлен, он работает.
через терминал получает и загружает файл, а если попробовать получить файл через windows cmd например, то идет долгая загрузка и ничего не происходит, порт 69 открыт, в чем может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скриншоты - зло.

Возможно, что-то на уровне фаерволла. Посмотрите на сервере tcpdump-ом на 69-м порту.

Comment: Ты сетевую загрузку через интернет хочешь сделать что ли?

Answer (score 1):

tftp и удаленное подключение - вещи не совместимые. Порт 69 пройдет через редко какого провайдера. Используйте ftp/ftps/sftp/http/nfs для передачи файлов